# Python 画像保存先指定

Tags: python, opencv

Python OpenCVを使っています。

```
cat_count = 0
for　(物体検出のループ):
    ・
    ・
    ・
    cat_count += label_name.count('Cat')
print(cat_count)

if cat_count == 1:
    cv2.imwrite('./Cat/', img)
```

物体を検出するたびにループされ
ラベルのついたバウンディングボックスが画像に現れる。
出力結果は猫が検出された数です。

出力結果が1の時だけ、Catというフォルダに保存したいのですがうまくいきません。教えてください。

追記
エラーは出ていませんが画像は保存されません。
ssd_kerasのソースを元に作成しています。

Comment: 画像のファイル名がありませんね。実際にはどういうコードになっていて、どういうエラーがでるのでしょうか？

Comment: 提示された断片的なコードだけから第三者が原因を判断するのは難しいと思います。`img` に正しいファイルパスが入っているのか、`if` 文にひっかからないのが原因なのか、サブディレクトリの `./Cat/` は予め存在するのか…等。なるべく他の人が再現可能な情報（最小限の実行可能なコード）を提示するようにしてください。 - https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

提示されているソースだけで言えば、nekketsuuuさんのコメントの通り、ファイル名まで含めて指定すべきところをフォルダ名だけしか指定していないためでしょう。

Catフォルダは作った上で、以下のようにしてみてください。

```
if cat_count == 1:
    cv2.imwrite("./Cat/SingleCat.jpg", img)
```

参考：
[OpenCV::imwrite](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imwrite)
[Python+OpenCV: cv2.imwrite](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20425724/9014308)
[cv2.imwrite で連番のファイル名で保存したい](https://teratail.com/questions/106811)

Comment: ありがとうございます！参考になりました！